# The argument type 'void Function(int)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function(int?)?'

Tags: android, flutter, dart

Hello for all I have problem so I want to best solution for this code
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uVa3n.png)

It shows The argument type

> '`void Function(int)`' can't be assigned to the parameter type '`void Function(int?)`?'.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please see "[ask]", "[Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648)" and "[MCVE]" and all their linked pages along with "[Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/128421)" and
"[Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812)"

Answer (score 2):

Update:

```
(int newColor) {...}
```

to

```
(int? newColor) {...}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is null safety error

define color variable like this:

```
int? color;
```

also change the following lines to this:

```
int? newColor;
saveColor(newColor!);
```

for more info about null safety:
https://dart.dev/null-safety